# Сохранение с помощю play services в unity

Tags: unity3d, google-play-services, save

Всем привет, как можно сделать  автоматичное сохранение в unity с помощю play services? Допустим у меня есть валюта в монетах и при каждом изменении щетчика монет происходит автоматичиское сохранение монет на аккаунт. Подкажите пожалуйста ещо документацию, где можно прочитать про ето все.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте посмотреть информацию тут
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juxeqLmABz4&feature=emb_logo

Comment: Я уже смотрел, но не помогло. Я нашол видео которое мне точно поможет, но у него не работаем ссылка на плагин Boomlagoon Json, он сказал что его можно легко найти, но я уже второй день пробую его найти и без результатов даже пробовал скачать другие но они не помагают. Написал ему на сайт и в коменты, но он не отвечает, вот ссылка на видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3nUBghKbfEw&ab_channel=ResoCoder